# objects missing in the 3D view (can be seen in collada export)

Tags: objects, 3d-view

Recently, a few of my objects have disappeared completely, and one of them appears completely black in 'texture' view, even though in the render view it appears normal.

The missing objects don't appear in render, but if I export to collada, they are present.

There are lamps that are missing, but they also appear to export in collada.

I don't want to delete these objects, I would just like to fix them.  Is there a way?

They appear in layers, I can sort of select them, but even with <kbd>w</kbd> > *clear all restricted* and viewing everything, they are missing.

Comment: Could you post a blend file with the problem?

Comment: Your objects might just be hidden. Press [Alt]+[H] to unhide everything on the current layer. Also make sure you are not in local view mode (press [Numpad-/] to toggle local/global view).

Comment: Nope, not hidden.  They seem glitched.

Comment: Without more information is hard to tell what the problem is. Please edit your question with images that show the problem, include any pertinent setting, or even better post a blend file.